# file conflict after writing to file in android studio and replacing it

Tags: android, file, kotlin, file-writing

I have a problem when I use write in kotlin. The app saves a file by overwriting it, after doing that I change the content of the file from inside my computer. (the files between my computer and the android devices are linked with synology drive)
So when I save the file form inside the application(kotlin code) and after that I change content in the file on my computer. The file doesn't replace the current file, it changes the name of the previous file with [NAMEFILE]-[DATE]_Conflict.
Example: 
App: save fileA.csv
Computer: Change content in fileA.csv
Android device: fileA.csv -> fileA_aug-30-110526-2022_Conflict.csv (original file without the changes) and creates new file fileA.csv

This is my code to safe the file:

```
fun saveControl(controlesProduct: ControlesProduct, newLoc:String = "")
{
    val otherFile= File(controlesProduct.path)
    val writer = otherFile.printWriter()
    writer.write("test")
    writer.close()
}
```

Nothing specials happens after that.
I have tried using bufferedWriter(). The same problem occurs when replacing the whole file.
 If we just read the file not write there isn't a problem

Comment: Which problem do you have? And is it because if changing content or changing file name?

Comment: as I mentioned before, The problem occurs when if have written in the file, on the app. And then i change the content of the file (on the pc, the file is linked in one way, from pc-> android device). The phone makes a copy of the original file with the same name but adding "_Conflict" to it and creates a new file with the original name(with the new content). Changing the name doesn't give me a problem

Comment: I still have no idea which problem you have.

Comment: I don't know how else to explain it. When I change the content of the file on my pc
(after the android app has written to it). the android device creates 2 files, one with the content that the app has written to and another file with the new content that is synced with my pc. The file that has been changed by the app has been renamed to fileA_Conflict.csv. And the file that has been modified by the pc stays the same filename.

Comment: I cannot follow you but besides that: what of that all is a problem for you,?

Comment: `When I change the content of the file on my pc (after the android app has written to it). the android device creates 2 files,` Well then you would have three files.

Comment: `, one with the content that the app has written to` ??? What would that be? I can not follow you.

Comment: sry, but it creates one file and changes the original file my bad. First the app on the android device changes the original file using outputstream. Then when the stream is closed, the pc changes the content of that file. When he does that the android device creates a new file with the content (that was already on the device after closing the outputstream) and replaces the original file with the file from my pc

Comment: `When he does that the android device creates a new file` You mean you Android app. But why would your Android app create a new file. You programmed your app. So why would you create a new file?

Comment: `and replaces the original file with the file from my pc` And why did you program that that all happens? And what do you consider to be the file from my pc? Sorry but it is still so unclear what you want and what happens instead. Please dont use comments to explain but edit your post. Write a post that everybody can understand.

Comment: I will leave it, I have found a workaround. just delete the conflict files. But I know it is hard to explain. And the app itself doesn't create the file it happens inside android itself. thank you for your patients